# Ошибка в коде php в массиве

Tags: php, echo

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$a = array(
    'name' => 'Nick',
    'soname' => 'Gromyko'
    );

    echo (Имя $a ['name']);
?>
```

пишет, что в 10 строке ошибка

Comment: `echo('Имя ' . $a['name']);` или `echo("Имя $a['name']");`

Comment: @kff, Во втором варианте нужны фигурные скобки: `echo("Имя {$a['name']}");`

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо. Ошибся.

Comment: Без фигурных скобок работает костыль: `"Name $a[name]"`, но крайне желательно воздержаться от этого. `php` трактует `name`, как неопределённую константу, и на всякий случай конвертирует её в строку. Очень ресурсоёмкая операция, если ей злоупотреблять. Да и куча нотисов в логах.

Comment: @NickGrom Если вы нашли решение, то отметьте один из ответов как окончательный.

Comment: Если ваш скрипт содержит только php не нужно использовать закрывающий тег ?>

Comment: @NickGrom вы ещё тут?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И не удивительно. Следует делать так:

```
echo 'Имя '.$a['name'];
```

Все слова и другое, что выводим с помощью echo, следует помещать в кавычки. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php).

Причём следует различать двойные и одинарные кавычки. В данном случае правильнее будет использовать одинарные ([Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)). Читай ниже!

**upd!!!** Касательно кавычек на последних версиях php можно [почитать вот тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#120160). Очень интересно и **опровергает вышесказанное**. В связи с этим оптимальный по быстродействию вариант следующий:

```
echo "Имя ${a['name']}";
```

Comment: Не нашёл в Документации про последнее предложение. *srcsm*

Comment: @vp_arth Прошу прощения. Забыл ссылку указать. Исправил.

Comment: А что где-то написано, что если нет необходимости внутри кавычек писать переменные НУЖНО использовать одинарные кавычки? Мне казалось этот вопрос остается на совести автора...

Comment: Вот и я про то же. Правильно будет - `В данном случае можно использовать любые`

Comment: @Дмитрий на совести автора. Но если ставить одинарные кавычки, компилятор сразу и однозначно определит содержимое кавычек как текст. А если двойные - будет тратить время на поиск внутри управляющих последовательностей и др. Стало быть, если только текст выводим (именно наш случай), то правильнее будет использовать одинарные.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/4LktQ/vld#output

Comment: @vp_arth Ну. Запускаем отдельно echo 'Hello, world!'; и echo "Hello, world!"; И на вкладке Performance видим, что с одинарными кавычками выполняется быстрее. Замерял три раза каждый вариант. Попробуйте (0.004 против 0.007). По крайней мере на последней версии php всё так. http://i.imgur.com/66UJ9V9.png

Comment: Ой, всё. Пусть будет так. Вы сами-то понимаете что замеряете?

Comment: @vp_arth Вы же сами мне на этот сайт дали ссылку. Объясните, пожалуйста. Я признаю свои ошибки. Так в чём дело?

Comment: Оба кода генерируют абсолютно идентичные опкоды. Разница в синтаксическо-лексическом разборе. Вы никогда не заметите эту разницу в dev-environment, а в production есть APCache или аналоги.

Comment: @vp_arth Может я и не сильно разбираюсь, но какая нам разница в том, что они оба генерируют один и тот же опкод? К чему-то одному можно разными по "длине" способами прийти. Вы говорите, что разница в "в синтаксическо-лексическом разборе". И разе это хоть мизерно не сказывается на времени компиляции и т.п? Да, есть OPCache (вы это имели ввиду, наверное, нет?). Пусть компилирует и хранит. Но ведь мы говорим не о том. Об основе - базисе.

Comment: А в чём смысл говорить о теории, если на практике результаты будут иными? Кстати, [по поводу теории](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#120160), свеженькое.

Comment: @vp_arth Хм... Неожиданно. И убедительно! Очень убедительно. Спасибо большое))

Comment: UPD Помог, Благодарен!

Comment: @NickGrom Отметьте вопрос как решённый, приняв один из ответов.

Answer (score 4):

Выбирайте какой нравится:

```
<?php

$a = ["name" => "User"];

// По сути просто как шаблон с переменной, на самом деле в данном случаее(printf/sprintf) лучше!
echo "Name {$a['name']}";
echo PHP_EOL;

// сначала печатает первую част, потом вторую... равансильно 2-м echo
echo "Name ", $a['name'];
echo PHP_EOL;


// Объединяет 2 строки в одну (конкатенация `.`) потом печатает.
echo "Name " . $a['name'];
echo PHP_EOL;

// http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php
// http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php
// Очень полезные функции форматирования, ну и код легче читать
printf ("Name %s", $a['name']);
echo PHP_EOL;

printf ("Name %s%s", $a['name'], PHP_EOL);

echo sprintf ("Name %s", $a['name']);
echo PHP_EOL;

// ПС: `PHP_EOL` платформенно независимое окончание строки ;)
```

Спор про двойные одинарные ковычки, ни о чем. Так экономия на спичках. Помните что `"` позволяют использовать в них переменные без конкотенации, а удобно это или нет зависит от использования!

```
<?php
    $a = "User";
    echo "Name $a";  // prints Name User
    echo 'Name $a';  // prints Name $a
```

Документация про строки в **PHP**:

http://php.net/language.types.string

Comment: Мы в обсуждениях таки вот к чему пришли (товарищ @vp_arth прислал) - http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#120160

Comment: @n.osennij Да всё равно, запрос к базе будет гораздо медленнее. Я вседа предпочту `sprintf` меньше путаницы с ковычками код читаеться легче.

Comment: А при чём тут база? Мы не о том говорим же.

Comment: @n.osennij При любом раскладе вывод не будет самой медленной(критичной) частью приложения(если это так, то надо смотреть на другие языки/способы). Поэтому оптимизация скорости подобным оброзом - пустая трата времени.

Comment: Ладно. Закроем холивар) Каждый что-то для себя вынес. Я так точно)

Comment: Помогло, Благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Исправьте строчку на:

```
echo "Имя " . $a['name'];
```